# overriding a constructor

Tags: overriding

This is a simple questions. I have researched this questions in my notebooks and books and the internet but cant find an answer

Why would we override the default constructor by adding parameters to it?

Comment: Because that's one way to override a constructor...?

Comment: This is overloading not overriding.

Comment: Do you mean the default constructor, provided by the compiler (public, no-argument) if you, the programmer, fail to provide a constructor?  Or, do you mean why have a constructor like:  public Student(String name) and public Student()?

Answer (score 0):

You would create a constructor for a class to manipulate its member variables according to whatever other conditions as soon as it's created. I get the impression you don't actually know what a constructor is.

Answer (score 0):

Many languages (like C++/C#/Java) automatically create default no-arguments constructor when none defined in the class explicitly.

When you create a constructor in a class with or without arguments usually compiler stop creating default auto-generated constructor (depending on language specification). This is done on assumption if you have some non default initialization than automatically generated one is likely to not create object in a state you would expect.

Since having constructor with arguments is natural way to create objects it is essentially lead to "removing" default auto-generated constructor which probably can be called "overriding default constructor".